# Understanding triple mixed quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I'm having a hard time understanding mixed quantifiers of this form: $$\forall x\exists y\forall z(...)$$ and similarly $$\exists x\forall y\exists z(...)$$

It really hurts my head to think about these. For all x, there exists a y, such that for all z?

Let's take as an example, a relation M, thought of as x being married to y, for the sake of visualizing this, even if it would make no sense in the real world. Stating: $$\forall x\exists y\forall z(M(x,y) \land M(x,z) \land M(y,z))$$ seems to mean that for all people x, there exists a person y, such that for all people z, x is married to y, and x is married to z, and y is married to z. What would that even mean? How can one unwind this expression, to more clearly see what is being said?

I have tried to somehow think about each quantifier one by one, but that seems to make no sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following formulae are equal: $$∀x∃y∀z(M(x,y)∧M(x,z)∧M(y,z))=∀x∃y(M(x,y)∧∀z(M(x,z)∧M(y,z)))$$ So its saying that for any person $x$, we can find another person $y$ such that $x$ and $y$ are married, and also, some other nonsense holds. Clearly, this is false; not every person is married.

Comment: I found it helpful to make the domain of quantification explicit for each quantifier, e.g. $\forall x: [x\in A \implies \exists y:[y\in B \land \forall z:[z \in C \implies P(x,y,z)]]]$

Answer (score 0):

For a mathematical example, see the "standard" [epsilon-delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) definition of limit :

> $\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta, \forall x \ldots$.

For a natural language example, see Jan von Plato, [Elements of Logical Reasoning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/110761077X) (2013), page 118 :

> A sequence of quantifiers such as $∀x∃y∀z$ is quite natural.
>
> > *There is for every person some problem on which every attempt will fail*.
>
> The three-place relation here is: person $x$ fails on problem $y$ in attempt $z$. This
>   example also illustrates the choice of a domain. In this case the domain seems to contain, at least, persons, problems, and attempts. There is a threeplace relation that we can write as $Fail(x, y, z)$, in which $x$ is a person, $y$ a problem, and $z$ an attempt. These have to go in the right places in the relation.
>
> The usual way to do it is to introduce predicates such as $Person(x), Problem(y)$, and $Attempt(z)$, and to write the formalization as in:
>
> > $Person(x) \land Problem(y) \land Attempt(z) \rightarrow Fail(x, y, z)$
>
> The condition for $Fail(x, y, z)$ can be lifted only if $x, y, z$ are appropriately
>   chosen.

---

*Note*

Regarding your example, you can rewrite it as a more "natural" one as follows :

> $∀x∃y[Father(y,x)∧∀z((z \ne x ∧ Father(y,z)) \rightarrow Brother(x,z))]$

which is equivalent to :

> $∀x∃y∀z[Father(y,x)∧((z \ne x ∧ Father(y,z)) \rightarrow Brother(x,z))]$